# InvalidCastException while using StartRecordToCustomSinkAsync

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am modifying `Media_capture_using_capture_device_sample` sample code. I want to use `StartRecordToCustomSinkAsync` instead of `StartRecordToStorageFileAsync`. In the example code I have just replaced the required API as below :

In `AdvancedCapture.xaml.cpp`,

instead of below API

```
create_task(m_mediaCaptureMgr->StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(recordProfile, this->m_recordStorageFile)).then([this](task<void> recordTask)
```

I have put

```
task<void>(m_mediaCaptureMgr->StartRecordToCustomSinkAsync(recordProfile,"GrayscaleTransform.GrayscaleEffect",nullptr)).then([this](task<void> recordTask)
```

[My intention is to receive frames in custom sink]

When I call  `StartRecordToCustomSinkAsync` it enters the immidiate try block executes `recordTask.get()` and then enters catch block with `InvalidCastException`

Pls help me to understand the scenario...

Thanks in advance